# Changing state does not trigger render

Tags: reactjs

I'm having a small issue with a component implementation.
Find the code below

```
var AroundMe = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){

        return({
            dances: [],
            events: this.props.events,
            user_coords: {}
        })
    },
    update_events: function(data){
        this.setState({events: data});
    },

    filter_by_geolocation: function(){
        var vm = this;
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                vm.setState({user_coords: {longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude}});
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/aroundme.json",
                    datatype: 'JSON',
                    data: vm.state.user_coords,
                    method: 'GET'
                }).done(function(response){
                    vm.update_events(response.aroundme);
                }.bind(vm));
            });
        } else {
            console.log("geo not supported")
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.filter_by_geolocation} className='btn btn-danger'>Locate me</button>
                <EventsList events={this.state.events} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Clicking on the button changes the events state but does not send the new value to to the Eventslist component.
What did I do wrong?
Thanks for your help!
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch. setState is asynchronous so you need to use a callback.

Change this:

```
vm.setState({user_coords: {longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude}});
$.ajax({
    url: "/aroundme.json",
    datatype: 'JSON',
    data: vm.state.user_coords,
    method: 'GET'
}).done(function(response){
    vm.update_events(response.aroundme);
}.bind(vm));
```

To this:

```
vm.setState({user_coords: {longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitude: position.coords.latitude}}, function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "/aroundme.json",
      datatype: 'JSON',
      data: vm.state.user_coords,
      method: 'GET'
  }).done(function(response){
      vm.update_events(response.aroundme);
  }.bind(vm));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunately it doesn't work either.
Tracing {this.state.events.length} shows the change of of state but looks like the underlaying component still recieves the orginal state

Comment: hmmm. That should have fixed it. Could you grant me access to a repo so I could help you debug?

Comment: I'll try to isolate this side of the project so you can check it out.
Find here a gist with the 2 components 
https://gist.github.com/folivi/163688f8f4d3c1ea9907
maybe there is a mistake in my implementation of the EventsList component.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: No worries, it would take quite a while to try and debug without access to the full repo, since the issue is related to what happens when data is updated. If you could generate a trimmed down repo using a local datastore and only the components that had the issues and made sure the new repo had the same issues, I could try and debug. As long as I can just spin something up, I can give something a shot. It would take too long to just try and trace the code though! With that being said, maybe try some console logging in your update_events function to see if it's even being called.

Comment: hi John, here is the repo with my source. https://github.com/folivi/eventApp.git I'm still stuck on the same issue. Thanks for your time. 
Folivi